# how to save multiple select box data into database

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, servlets

i have to send form data which have multiselect boxes to a servlet using jquery ajax function
for that i am using jquery serialize function

but i am getting this string   `mothertonguelist=English&mothertonguelist=French&mothertonguelist=Chinese`

you can see that **mothertonguelist** is coming multiple times  , how do i get these values
inside servlet.

also
what is the efficient way to save these multiple select box values in database so that it can be easy for me to populate these values back to the multiple select box .

also tell me some good way to populate the values inside the form from the servlet.

i don't want to use xml and and i have never used Json...

Thanks........

Comment: 1st problem solved. If anyone wants to get multiple box values in servlet then use this        `String[] mothertonguelist = request .getParameterValues("mothertonguelist");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone wants to get multiple box values in servlet then use this

```
String[] mothertonguelist = request .getParameterValues("mothertonguelist");
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just parse each selected item out of the string that is returned, then store the items in a database? My assumption is that mothertonguelist comes through multiple times because it is selected multiple times.

Comment: No mothertonguelist is name of that multiple select box and their are multiple different values selected in that as shown in my question....

Comment: Did you select English, French and Chinese in the multi-select box when you got the string joined by the &'s on the backend?